# How to serve static resources in user home directory

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some pictures in ~/YYT/ProfilePicture folder. I want to make spring boot serve these pictures as static resources. Request url is like "http://localhost:8080/ProfilePicture/4/takeovertheworld.jpg". I have tried writing `spring.resources.static-locations=file:~/YYT/` property in application.properties file. I have also tried using `WebMvcConfigurer`. None of them work.

```
@Configuration
public class WebStaticResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        String homeDirectory = "file:" + Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "YYT/ProfilePicture").toString();
        System.out.println(homeDirectory);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/ProfilePicture/**").addResourceLocations(homeDirectory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `homeDirectory` is missing is missing a trailing `/`.

Use `path.toUri()` to generate a valid uri and use that afterwards.

```java
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "YYT/ProfilePicture");
String homeDirectory = path.toUri().toString();
registry.addResourceHandler("/ProfilePicture/**").addResourceLocations(homeDirectory);
```

Now the `homeDirectory` string should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The path should be changed as below:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/YYT/
```